# How can I create a carousel displaying specific posts in a jekyll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jekyll, liquid

I would like to create a carousel displaying specific posts, like a sort of "featured posts" layout.

The jekyll theme that I use has bootstrap 4 installed, what I did was taking the code for a bootstrap carousel.

I thought of adding a category "slider" in the front matter to mark the posts I want to display in the carousel, but I do not know how to use liquid well enough so it can picks the specific posts I want, I am a beginner when it comes to jekyll.

I have also tried to use the Slider/Carousel plugin, and managed to have the posts displayed rather than the placeholder images, but again, I don't know how to pinpoint specific posts.

I would probably prefer to use the bootsrap slider and manage to display certain posts within it, as it might be easier to customize for a beginner like me.

To make it clear, what I want is to use a carousel on jekyll to display specific posts but I don't kno how to use liquid well enough.

Here is the code of the bootstrap 4 slider, without any liquid

```
!--Carousel Wrapper-->
<div id="carousel-example-2" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
  <!--Indicators-->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <!--/.Indicators-->
  <!--Slides-->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="view">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(68).jpg"
          alt="First slide">
        <div class="mask rgba-black-light"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3 class="h3-responsive">Light mask</h3>
        <p>First text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <!--Mask color-->
      <div class="view">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(6).jpg"
          alt="Second slide">
        <div class="mask rgba-black-strong"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3 class="h3-responsive">Strong mask</h3>
        <p>Secondary text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <!--Mask color-->
      <div class="view">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(9).jpg"
          alt="Third slide">
        <div class="mask rgba-black-slight"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3 class="h3-responsive">Slight mask</h3>
        <p>Third text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/.Slides-->
  <!--Controls-->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-example-2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-example-2" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
  <!--/.Controls-->
</div>
<!--/.Carousel Wrapper-->
```

And here is what I tried to do with Slider/Carousel, I added {% for post in site.posts %}, it show all my posts, but it doesn't work well at all, and i don't want all the posts in the slider.

```
{% assign letterstring = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n" %}
{% assign letters = letterstring | split: ',' %}

<div class="carousel__holder">
    <div class="carousel">
        {% for post in site.posts %}
    
          <input class="carousel__activator" type="radio" name="carousel" id="{{ letters[forloop.index0] }}" {% if forloop.first %}checked="checked"{% endif %} />
        
{% endfor %}
        {% for post in site.posts %}
    
          {% if forloop.index == forloop.length %}
            {% assign nextindex = 0 %}
          {% else %}
            {% assign nextindex = forloop.index0 | plus: 1 %}
          {% endif %}
          {% assign nextletter = letters[nextindex] %}
          {% if forloop.index0 == 0 %}
            {% assign previndex = forloop.length | minus: 1 %}
          {% else %}
            {% assign previndex = forloop.index0 | minus: 1 %}
          {% endif %}
          {% assign prevletter = letters[previndex] %}
          <div class="carousel__controls">
              <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--backward" for="{{ prevletter }}"></label>
              <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--forward" for="{{ nextletter }}"></label>
          </div>
        
{% endfor %}
        <div class="carousel__track">
          <ul>
            {% for post in site.posts %}
    
            <li class="carousel__slide" style="background-image: url('{{ post.image }}');"><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
             
{% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel__indicators">
            {% for post in site.posts %}
    
              <label class="carousel__indicator" for="{{ letters[forloop.index0] }}"></label>
            
{% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to pinpoint specific posts

Use the code below (to filter only posts form a certain author).

```
{% assign sorted-posts = site.posts | where: "author","sharathdt" %}
{% for post in sorted-posts limit: 5 %}
  <li>{{post.title}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Source: https://blog.webjeda.com/jekyll-filters/

This works for any variable, so you can also filter on `is_featured: true`.

Comment: I used {% for post in site.tags.test %}, created a tag to the posts that I called "test" so it owuld display only those with this tag

I also used {% assign sorted-posts = site.posts | where: "tags","test" %} like you suggested for a similar case, not a carousel, just a post display. Both seem to work